# Extremely trivial integral $\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (n - m) t} \mathrm{d}t = \delta_{nm}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

How does $$\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (n - m) t} \mathrm{d}t = \delta_{nm}$$ where
$$
\delta_{nm} = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n = m$}\\
0 & \text{if $n \neq m$}
\end{cases}
$$

$t, \tau \in \mathbb{R}$.

When $n \neq m$, 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (n - m) t} \mathrm{d}t & = \frac{1}{\tau} \int_0^\tau \cos{((n - m)t)}\mathrm{d}t + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\tau} \int_0^\tau \sin{((n - m)t)}\mathrm{d}t\\
& = \frac{1}{\tau (n - m)}(\sin{((n - m)\tau) - \sin(0))} - \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\tau (n - m)}(\cos{((n - m)\tau)} -\cos(0))\\
& = \frac{\sin{(\tau(n - m)})}{\tau (n - m)} -  \frac{\mathrm{i} \cos{(\tau(n - m))}}{\tau (n - m)} - 1
\end{align}

How does the above expression evaluate to $0$ when $n \neq m$? I know this is very trivial but I'm unable to prove it.

Edit:

I guess this is a simple typo. $\tau$ is equal to $2\pi / \omega$ where $\omega$ is the fundamental angular frequency. There should be an $\omega$ in the exponential term. The integral should be $$\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{\omega} (n - m) t} \mathrm{d}t.$$ Then everything is alright.

Comment: Your calculation works only when $n\neq m$ (but the result is not correct, there is no reason that if $n\neq m$ this integral is $0$). When $n=m$, then $e^{i(n-m)t}=1$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Ah, yes. My bad. $\tau = 2 \pi / \omega$ where $\omega$ is the fundamental angular frequency.

Comment: Where is the angular frequency in the exponential term then?

Comment: @PeterForeman Yeah, I guess this must be a simple typo. The integral should be $$\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{\omega}(n - m) t} \mathrm{d}t$$ Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, but if you were integrating over the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$, then it would, due to the periodicity of the trig functions. I think this must be what is meant.

Greg